# How to run SWING applications written in Jython?

Tags: java, swing, jython

I've installed Jython and trying to run swing application that's bundled in installation package. I set the JYTHON_PATH and PATH to bin subdirectory and I run: "jython Console.py"  I see the console for a split second and it disappears.  Same behavior with other examples.  What am I missing?

I have MacOSX 10.6 and Jython 2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a bug when you simply fire `jython Console.py`. The behavior is same on my Vista machine with Jython 2.5.

Though when you execute it like this `jython -i Console.py` it works fine. I have tested it on my Vista machine.

Though command line help says

```
-i       : inspect interactively after running script and force prompts, 
           even if stdin does not appear to be a terminal
```